# Show value in table from a model with template in django

Tags: python, django, templates, model, show

I want to make a website to manage a bread production but I am facing 2 problems.

I have a model bread (Pain) that allows me to create a bread and to give that bread a starting price.
(nom_pain = name , prix_HT = price)

```
class Pain(models.Model):
nom_pain = models.CharField(max_length=25,primary_key=True)
prix_HT = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2)
pain_decouverte = models.BooleanField(null=False)
def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.nom_pain)
```

I have a model Group (Groupe) that represents different group of clients.
(nom_groupe = name)

```
class Groupe(models.Model):
nom_groupe = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.nom_groupe)
```

I wish to match the price of each bread to a group of clients on one page and then display it in a table chart (inserting the bread prices in the blank cells)

```
            | Bread 1 | Bread 2 | Bread 3 |
    Group 1 |  0.5    |  0.6    |         |      
    Group 2 |   1     |         |   0.5   |
    Group 3 |  0.5    |  0.4    |   0.7   |
```

My first problem is that I can’t save 2 times a group/bread in my model Price (Prix) (I wanted it in the form of Group / Bread / Price).

The second problem is that I don’t know how to display my table chart in my template. I can only display the breads and the groups of clients available.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: You need to define a many-to-many field with a through table that stores the price.

Comment: how to avoid data duplicate in a model ?

Comment: with a `UniqueConstraint`.

Comment: I know what you say but i have an error. Probably in my code

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `ManyToManyField` between `Pain` and `Groupe`. This `ManyToManyField` has as [**`through=…`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through), the `Prix` model:

```
class Groupe(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Pain(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    pain_decouverte = models.BooleanField()
    groupes = models.ManyToManyField('client.Groupe', related_name='pains', through='facturation.PainPrix')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom

class PainPrix(models.Model):
    pain = models.ForeignKey('pain.Pain', related_name='prix', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    groupe = models.ForeignKey('client.Groupe', related_name='prix', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prix = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['pain', 'groupe'], name='prix_unique')
        ]
```

Comment: Thank's for answer. he doesn't work when I want migrate.
But in model Pain i want to have "prix_HT" because i get the price if doesn't exist in model Prix

Comment: @Aomichi: but the price depends on the `Groupe` if I understood it correctly, so then it makes no sense at all to store a price in the `Pain`. If you want a basic price, you still can add one.

Likely the migration does not work because of the *current* state of the models. It might make sense to drop the database, and restart migrating from scratch.

Comment: Yes but all groupe don't have necessarily another price ( It is to facilitate management because there are many exceptions).Yes I tried by deleting the database and migrations but error to establish the relationship

Comment: @Aomichi: exactly *what* error do you get? Note that you better do *not* use `nom` (or `pain_nom`) as primary key, since collation in a database can be quite cumbersome.

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'Pain' from partially initialized module 'pain.models' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: @Aomichi: ah but you defined the `Pain` model in another app?

Comment: @Aomichi: in that case, you should not *import* it, but use a string literal, such that Django can "tie the knot".

Comment: Yes , Pain is in PainApp , Groupe in ClientApp and PrixPain is in FacturationApp

Comment: @Aomichi: well you can use a string like `'app_name.ModelName'` as in the updated answer to avoid making (circular) imports.

Comment: Well i have the same error >.< : 
ImportError: cannot import name 'Pain' from partially initialized module 'pain.models' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\alexb\Desktop\le-fournil-gestion\pain\models.py)

Comment: @Aomichi: yes, because as said, you need to remove the import statements as well :p. After all circular imports are simply invalid Python.

Comment: ERRORS:
<function ManyToManyField.contribute_to_class.<locals>.resolve_through_model at 0x040C3F10>: (models.E022) <function ManyToManyField.contribute_to_class.<locals>.resolve_through_model at 0x040C3F10> contains a lazy reference to pain.painprix, but app 'pain' doesn't provide model 'painprix'.
facturation.PainPrix.pain: (fields.E302) Reverse accessor for 'PainPrix.pain' clashes with field name 'Pain.prix'.

Comment: HINT: Rename field 'Pain.prix', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'PainPrix.pain'.
facturation.PainPrix.pain: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'PainPrix.pain' clashes with field name 'Pain.prix'.
        HINT: Rename field 'Pain.prix', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'PainPrix.pain'.
pain.Pain.groupes: (fields.E331) Field specifies a many-to-many relation through model 'PainPrix', which has not been installed.

Comment: @Aomichi: since the through model is defined in a different app, you again need to format it as `app_name.ModelName`...

Comment: @Aomichi: I think it is probably better to first understand *what* is happening. That usually makes working more effective.

Comment: He works ! Thank you ! Yes i know my method is bad. I have read the documentation but have really difficult and have a deadline.
I will be able to devote myself to the second problem !